# GPS not working in my application but works in Google Maps

Tags: android, gps, location, samsung-mobile, galaxy-tab

I have a strange issue with the GPS-component on the Samsung Galaxy Tab (GT-P7310): GPS works fine in Google Maps, but does not provide any location in my own application. Although my application works fine on my Samsung Galaxy S2.

I am calling the location-service like this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false));
// Constantly update the location
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false), 0, 0, listener);
```

but all I get is `null` as location and the callback-listener is never called.

The Tablet is running Android 4.2.2 with CyanogenMod 10.1-20130512-UNOFFICIAL-p5wifi. Location access is turned on (otherwise Google Maps wouldn't work too).

My app has the following permissions set in its Manifest:

- ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- INTERNET

Any ideas, why I get no location on this device?

Comment: Turned out, that the device had an bad antenna and no GPS-position. The code above only went for GPS-location (no network). GMaps on the other side used NETWORK_PROVIDER, so it worked. See http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ for an excellent tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
you can use `GPS` instead of selecting best provider by deciding criteria.

**Example:**

replace

```
    Location currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false));
// Constantly update the location
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false), 0, 0, listener);
```

with

```
    Location currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
// Constantly update the location
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

**Explaination:**

Depending on your application's use case, you can to choose a specific location provider
i.e. `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` or `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`

Alternatively, you can provide some input criteria such as accuracy, power requirement, monetary cost, and so on, and let Android decide a closest match location provider

```
    // Retrieve a list of location providers that have fine accuracy, no monetary cost, etc
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
String providerName = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
//and then you can make location update request with selected best provider
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 0, 0, listener);
```

Have a look at [how to use locationmanager](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) , [how to specify Criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html) and [how getBestProvider method works](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29) for reference

I hope it will be helpful !!